# How do you get CID and signal strength of all surrounding cell towers in Android 9 and above?

Tags: android, gsm, signal-strength, cellid

Ever since `NeighbouringCellInfo()` was depreciated in Android 9, I have found no way to get the signal strength of towers other than that of the one my Samsung S8 is connected to.

I am designing an app that requires the above information for the algorithm to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

[According to the official Google documentation on NeighboringCellInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/NeighboringCellInfo), you're now supposed to use [CellInfo instead](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellInfo.html).

> This class was deprecated in API level 29.
>
> This class should not be used by any app targeting Android Q or higher. Instead callers should use CellInfo.

Comment: I had already checked that, but there was nothing in CellInfo that I could use to find the information i needed for all the cell towers though. Thanks for the speedy reply!

Comment: Sorry to hear about CellInfo not having all the info; honestly, I never had to use either, so I cannot comment on your specific needs. Perhaps if you expand how you were using Neighboring cell info, we can try to find where this information lives (if it's still open).

Comment: Well I'm trying to show the top 6 nearest towers ordered according to strength in my app, so I want to use the cell tower ID and signal strength to do that. I'm trying to figure out the rest, but if I can get the above minimum, I'm probably good to go.

Comment: @pranavbhatt my app also need to find the neighbor cell info and single strength .. can you pls help me with that.. i am finding any solution